# KeyError in django when using a textarea

Tags: python, django

I want to do a very simple operation : 1-taking some info form the form 2-saving the data in the database
But i get this error and i don't know the reason of it! can you please help .

this is the forms.py :

```
class ContactForm(forms.Form):
title = forms.CharField(max_length=500)
phone_mail = forms.CharField(max_length=30)
body = forms.Textarea()
```

this is the models.py :

```
class Contact(models.Model):
title = models.CharField(max_length=500)
phone_mail = models.CharField(max_length=30)
text = models.TextField()
```

this is the views.py :

```
def contact(request):
if request.method == 'POST':
    form = forms.ContactForm(request.POST)
    if form.is_valid():
        data = form.cleaned_data
        Contact.objects.create(title = data['title'] , text = data['body'] , phone_mail = data['phone_mail'])
        return redirect('accounts:profile')
else :
    form = forms.ContactForm()
con = {'form' : form}
return render(request , 'home/contact.html' , con)
```

And this is the form :

```
            <form class="row g-3 p-3" method="post">
            {% csrf_token %}
            <div class="col-md-6">
              <label for="title" class="form-label">title</label>
              <input type="text" class="form-control" id="title" name="title">
            </div>
            <div class="col-md-6">
              <label for="phone_mail" class="form-label">phone or email</label>
              <input type="text" class="form-control" id="phone_mail" name="phone_mail">
            </div>
            <div class="col-12">
              <label for="inputtext" class="form-label">text:</label>
              <textarea type="text" class="form-control" name="body" id="inputtext" minlength="20" maxlength="10000" required></textarea>
            </div>
            <div class="col-12">
              <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Send</button>
            </div>
          </form>
```

And i get this error for them when i use the form to send the data :

```
KeyError at /contact/ 'body'

error line = Contact.objects.create(title = data['title'] , text = data['body'] , phone_mail = data['phone_mail'])
```

Comment: you're using field name as ```text``` in class but in request you're using ```body```. Have same name both the places as per requirements.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You got this error because you have written text instead of body.

models.py:

instead:

```
text = models.TextField()
```

try this:

```
body = models.TextField()

class Contact(models.Model):
      title = models.CharField(max_length=500)
      phone_mail = models.CharField(max_length=30)
      body = models.TextField() #changed here text to body
```

Here in forms.py file:

change this:

```
class ContactForm(forms.Form):
```

To:

```
class ContactForm(forms.ModelForm):
```

Comment: still does not work !

Comment: did you migrate after changing

Comment: yes i did that to

Comment: How you did migration

Comment: python3 manage.py makemigrations and also manage.py migrate

Comment: first delete your migration folder and do migrations manually like this:   python3 manage.py makemigrations appanme                     python3 manage.py sqlmigrate appname 0001         python3 manage.py migrate